# React-native: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed - Build Phases, no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was trying to build a react-native project on iOS, but the project had been developed mainly for Android for quite some time.

So I faced this **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**.

Even though I clicked on the error message, XCode (14 and 15 beta) did not take me to the error. But later I learned the error could be seen on the last icon in the main left menu bar.

[image]

By navigating there I found the details of the error XCode was complaining about:

```
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am using `nx` to manage a monorepo, so I thought I just needed to add `../../` to that path, because my `node_modules` were in the root of the monorepo.

But the error continues, what should I do? Any help is appreciated.